# How can I quickly make several classes inherit from a specific one?

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance

I'm working on a project in Eclipse, there is a package where I have about 73 classes. I've created a super class that I'll use to make an implementation of `toString()` using reflection. What I want to do is to make all the classes into that package to inherit from this super class, and of course, I want to do it quickly, using a plug in or whatever is possible.

To be more specific, I have 4 packages:

```
package.bean
package.bean.packA
package.bean.packB
package.bean.pcakC
```

I have created my super class in package.bean.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Could just use `sed`, if you know some specifics about the classes in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `extends`

i.e.

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass
{

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Andy. I'm sorry I was not clear enough. I know how to extend it, what I'm looking for is to quickly do it for my 73 classes instead of doing it manually for each one of them.

Comment: No Eclipse plugin for that to my knowledge, I will just copy and paste the "extends SuperClass" part.

Comment: Ouch, I was afraid you were going to say that :(

Comment: Do all the classes have a toString already?  If so, you could try right clicking on the sub class -> refactor -> extract super class?

Comment: some of them do, some of them don't. What is that option for?

Comment: Check out part 2,  http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.2-200606291905/new_noteworthy/eclipse-news-part2.html

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance in not available in java , for that we have use interfaces .